# Amqp protocol with Activemq

Tags: activemq-classic, amqp

Sorry for my previous post. I'm trying to send message with Jmeter, i've download it on github, with AMQP plugin for rabbitmq. In my activemq i setup amqp protocol

And get 100% of errors in Jmeter, in  log i see this error, and something about qpid proton.
Caused by:

```
org.apache.qpid.proton.engine.TransportException: org.apache.qpid.proton.engine.TransportException: AMQP header mismatch value 0, expecting 1. In state: HEADER5
        at org.apache.qpid.proton.engine.TransportResultFactory$TransportResultImpl.checkIsOk(TransportResultFactory.java:116)
        at org.apache.qpid.proton.engine.impl.TransportImpl.input(TransportImpl.java:220)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.amqp.AmqpProtocolConverter.onFrame(AmqpProtocolConverter.java:230)
```

What does in mean? And how i can fix this. Thank you

Comment: Please work on providing more information in your questions as well as what you've tried and what has gone wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell with such limited information but I would guess that you are attempting to connect to the broker with a client that speaks AMQP 0.10 or earlier while the ActiveMQ broker only speaks AMQP v1.0.  Use an AMQP 1.0 client to send the messages and it will probably work.

Comment: So i need to install amqp v1.0? Or qpid proton with new version? I thought that activemq 5.10 use amqp 1.0

Comment: ActiveMQ is using AMQP 1.0 it looks like whatever you are using to connect to it is not.

Comment: Ok i'll try to find another amqp libraries  v1.0 for jmeter maybe, and then test again.

Comment: Running python script from aactivemq/example/amqp/python, was same error, so i just install qpid proton, and run script again, and in my webconsole i see that was create topic, and one listener, i send 5000 messages but they didnt appear in console. So.. i think my jmeter is not working properly with activemq amqp protocol.

Comment: Hmm dont understand why when sending 100 msg, webconsole is empty,and listener dont closing, but when i setup in script to send ... 5 or 25 msgs sometimes 50,  they appear in console and listener closed. Why so?

Comment: Please close this issue out and ask new one with plenty of details.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the Qpid AMQP client library which is supporting AMQPv1.0